# Unable to probe video laravel ffmpeg

Tags: laravel

I have been following this tutorial on https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg and I am trying to resize my video files and it wont do it. I am constantly getting unable to probe. Whats wrong? Here is my code

```
         $vid = $request->file('vive');
         $filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
           $vid = $request->file('vive');

     $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
   'ffmpeg.binaries'  => "/ffmpeg.exe",
   'ffprobe.binaries' => "/ffprobe.exe"
]);

FFMpeg::open($filename)
    ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
        $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(140, 80));
    });
```

Comment: It looks like the unable to probe error is what it throws when it can't locate the file. Make sure your `$filename` is correct

Comment: Oh wow i see what you're saying because i get this error Unable to probe C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\public\app\export-wmv.wmv meaning the video file is not in the public/app folder but when I added the video in the public/app folder that's when it went through. But I don't get it i'm not saving the files there i'm saving it in my amazon s3 bucket. Why does the video have to be there?

Comment: Actually, I think the `FFMpeg::open()` function defaults to the storage location (which is defined in your filesystem config), which is probably why it can't find it. I'll update my answer with an alternate method.

Comment: @JPark Wow, so how are people who go on my site be able to upload their video and have it resized by ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package uses your `filesystem.php` config file to determine the location of where it is opening the file from. For example, the `local` disk points to your `storage/app` path, as defined in the config:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
```

If you wanted, you could set up a new "disk" in the config that points to the `app/` directory (where your file is being saved), though I wouldn't recommend this approach. Your best bet would be to configure PHP to upload your files directly to the storage directory.

Alternatively, you can simply store your file in the storage directly from the input object:

```
$filename = Input::file('vive')->getClientOriginalName();

$storagePath = 'uploads/temp';
if (!Storage::exists($storagePath)) {
    Storage::makeDirectory($storagePath);
}

Input::file('vive')->storeAs($storagePath, $filename);

FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')->open($storagePath . '/' . $filename)->addFilter(function ($filters) {
    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(140, 80));
});
```

Comment: Oh, could also be because of the `uniqid()` you are appending to `$vid`. try removing that first.

Comment: Okay I will try that. But I need to tell you this project of mine is going on the web. Am I going to have to anything different?

Comment: can you answer this for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799136/laravel-ffmpeg-object-of-class-could-not-be-converted-to-string

Comment: @JayJay123 Sorry, was out sick the past few days. Try posting again, unless you solved it yourself.

Comment: Hey its okay. I hope you're feeling a lot better now. I've manage to get through everything with the help you have given me. You've really helped me. Right now I am just trying to customize the error handler messages in Laravel I really don't want users to see the default error message that laravel has already. I really want to thank you so much, you have really helped!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it. Happy to help anytime.